# Android sqlite insert with error code 19: constraint failed

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have looked through other questions about this topic, but none of the answers apply and/or work for me.  I'm getting a 'SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed' error when I try to insert into my DB.

Here's my database:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class StrongDbAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";



    public static final String WORKOUT_STATE = "workoutState";

    public static final String SQUAT_LABEL = "squatLabel";




    private static final String TAG = "StrongDbAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;



    /**
     * Database creation sql statement
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement , "
        + "title text, workoutState text ," +
        " squatLabel text );";



    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public StrongDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /**
     * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
     * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
     * signal the failure
     * 
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public StrongDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }


    /**
     * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.

     */
    public long createNote(String title, String squatLabel) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        //initialValues.put(WORKOUT_STATE, workoutState);
        initialValues.put(SQUAT_LABEL, squatLabel);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the note with the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all notes
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                WORKOUT_STATE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, WORKOUT_STATE}, KEY_ROWID + "='" + rowId+"'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    /**
     * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId

     * @param rowId id of note to update
     * @param title value to set note title to
     * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        //args.put(WORKOUT_STATE, workoutState);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

And here is the insert method from my WorkoutEdit class

```
//Saves all the data to the database
    private void saveState() {
        String title = workoutState;
        String squatLabel = squats.getText().toString();


        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, squatLabel);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title);
        }
    }
```

And finally, my LogCat!

```
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575): Error inserting squatLabel=Squats - 45 title=WorkoutB
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_execute(Native Method)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.execute(SQLiteStatement.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1521)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.StrongDbAdapter.createNote(StrongDbAdapter.java:163)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit.saveState(WorkoutEdit.java:232)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at com.anapoleon.android.stronglifts.WorkoutEdit.onPause(WorkoutEdit.java:214)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:4046)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2762)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
08-04 23:09:22.009: E/Database(26575):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to figure out which database constraint in your SQLite database is being violated by your insert. The best way that I know of to do that is to visually verify each constraint against the data you're trying to insert.

To get a list of constraints for each table, you can execute the following SQL:

```
select sql from sqlite_master 
where type='table' and name='your_table_name';
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I sound stupid but where would I execute this SQL?